# TypeInitializationError when using static field

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, error-handling

Maybe it's an easy one, but I'm just starting with C# and can't figure out what I did wrong.

I was making a simple ping pong application, it worked properly, but suddenly a piece of code started throwing this error. Then I changed the game's main Form to a raw window's form, but the crash is still there.

```
Form form = new Form();

static void Main() {
  Application.Run(form); //<-- Throwing the Crash
}
```

The next image says it all, I really appreciate any help, even the slighter one. Thanks ^^

[The Error thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpX5k.png)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the form?

Comment: What do you mean by stepping? I'm using the raw windows form, with no modifications. Anyways, this used to work fine this morning, but now it's crashing, I did no modifications neither to windows form or to the form I was using before.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the error message.  The type initializer for *`Program`* is what's throwing the exception.  That type initializer has a few things happening, including:

```
new StartScreen()
new Settings()
new SettingsManager()
```

and possibly more that we don't see in the screen shot.

Something in the type initializer for `Program` is failing.  Examine the exception for more information.  Also, move some of that logic to constructors (static or instance as appropriate) to make it easier to debug.

(Or as I like to say, a `TypeInitializationException` is a fancy way of saying, "You have too much happening outside of methods.")

Comment: Thanks a lot! the problem was in 'new Settings()'. I used to have only settings and settingsManager constructor as static, I added the other ones trying to fix this error.

Answer (score -1):

The line

```
Form form = new Form();
```

is executed when you first access the variable form.
In this case it's in this line:

```
Application.Run(form);
```

So the constructor of the class Form threws an error

Comment: This is not true at all.

Comment: Hmm, nope, that's not the issue. I've tried too declaring the form field in the Main method, still the same crash. Thanks anyways ^.^

Comment: `"So the constructor of the class Form threws an error"` - Then why would the error say that it's being thrown by the class `Program`?

Comment: Oh, it seems I missed the other static variables because I was only looking on the form variable, sorry